# Viewing a PDF file as a response looks weird in Postman

Tags: pdf, post, postman, node.js-fs

I am sending a pdf file as a response to a POST request. But when I view the response in Postman, that looks weird as it's missing some spots. When I open that pdf in a browser it looks perfect.

Why is that? I don't think there is an error in code because when I open the pdf in browser, it is perfectly generated. Anyway I am attaching the code.

```
router.post('/getPdf', auth.authenticateToken, function (req, res) {
    const orderDetails = req.body;
    const pdfPath = './generated_pdf/' + orderDetails.uuid + '.pdf';
    if (fs.existsSync(pdfPath)) {
        res.contentType("application/pdf");
        fs.createReadStream(pdfPath).pipe(res);
    }
    else {
        var productDetailsReport = JSON.parse(orderDetails.productDetails);
        ejs.renderFile(path.join(__dirname, '', "report.ejs"), { productDetails: productDetailsReport, name: orderDetails.name, email: orderDetails.email, contactNumber: orderDetails.contactNumber, paymentMethod: orderDetails.paymentMethod, totalAmount: orderDetails.totalAmount }, (err, results) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return res.status(500).json(err);
            }
            else {
                pdf.create(results).toFile('./generated_pdf/' + orderDetails.uuid + ".pdf", function (err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        return res.status(500).json(err);
                    }
                    else {
                        res.contentType("application/pdf");
                        fs.createReadStream(pdfPath).pipe(res);
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }

})
```

[image: This is what I see]

When I'm sending the request again and again, it's changes the blank spots only (position of spots changes).

Comment: Have you viewed the downloaded PDFs anywhere else to rule out a PDF rendering issue in Postman?

Comment: @KJ I'm using the postman desktop app